# What's the name of the song and artist in Freezing Vibration episode 4 at about 9minutes in?

Tags: music, freezing

In Freezing Vibration episode 4 a girl with headphones fights another girl to a tune that has muffled singing and a piano playing. It occurs about 9minutes into the episode.

Can anyone tell me the name of the artist and the song?

Comment: I don't know the first, but the second is from the second movement of the moonlight sonata.

Comment: Since the first OST for Freezing Vibration won't be out until Jan 29, 2014 ([vgmdb page](http://vgmdb.net/album/41575)), you might not have an answer until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The girl is Charles Bonaparte and the song is called: Vent Debout - Masaru Yokoyama

The song is found on Freezing Vibration OST volume 2 track 17. As found on [wikipedia page](http://freezing.wikia.com/wiki/Freezing:_Vibration)
And the actual song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtbKHkvK_Oo

It is first heard in freezing vibration episode 4, when Charles debut's her combat skills in the fighting form that she calls "Typhon Tempest".

Comment: Do you have some more details to go along with this. Like why you think it is this series, maybe a short excerpt of the wiki, and if you do so, why not include a link to the wiki as well